# How to communicate two components using interfaces?

Tags: java, interface

I'm developing a component-based software and I have two components that communicate with each other. I have a **Reservation Component** that manage the reservation process and a **Resort Component** that manage the resort details (available rooms, room details, clients, etc.). The **Reservation Component** have an **IReservation** interface and the **Resort Component** have an **IResort** interface. The interfaces are shown below.

**IReservation**

```
public interface IReservation{

    void makeReservation(Client c);
    RoomDetails getRoomDetails(int roomNumber);
}
```

**IResort**

```
public interface IResort{

    RoomDetails getRoomDetails(int roomNumber);
}
```

Notice that both interfaces have the same method `getRoomDetails`.

I would like that when the **Reservation Component** need to get the room details, the **IReservation** interface pass the call to the **Resort Component** through the **IResort** interface, so the **Resort Component** can execute de **getRoomDetails** and return the room details to the **Reservation Component** through **IReservation** interface.
 So how can I make the **Reservation Component** pass the call to the **Resort Component** and get the room details from it?

Comment: Does the solutions need to be interfaces? Otherwise you could declase `IReservation` as abstract class and give it an attribute of type `IResort` and a final method `getRoomDetails(int)`, which simply forwards the call to the `IResort` attribute.

Comment: i would add new interface `IRoomInfo` with `getRoomDetails` and let both `IReservation` and `IResort` exteds it. `IReservation` implementation will impelement `IRoomInfo.getRoomDetail` as call to `IResort.getRoomDetails`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interface cannot pass calls to another interface - only concrete implementations can do this.

When you create your Reservation component (implements `IReservation`), pass it a reference to your Resort component (implements `IResort`), in the constructor or via a setter method.

Then simply call the `IResort` component's `.getRoomDetails()` method from your Reservation component, when it needs room details.

(That's assuming you do indeed want separate components for IReservation and IResort, and that you want to keep those two interfaces as described; you could, for example, implement both interfaces with the same class, or create a new interface to hold `getRoomDetails` as described in the comment by Krab)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to drop the condition that both have to be Interfaces, you can enforce your condition by declaring `IReservation` as abstract class:

```
// implements is not necessarily needed, but here it does fit since each
// Reservation is bound to an IResort
public abstract class AReservation implements IResort {

    IResort resort;

    public AReservation(IResort resort) {
        this.resort = resort;
    }

    abstract public void makeReservation(Client c);

    // forward getRoomDetails to resort's getRoomDetail,
    // make method final to prevent overriding.
    public final RoomDetails getRoomDetails(int roomNumber) {
        return this.resort.getRoomDetails(roomNumber);
    }
}

public interface IResort {

    public RoomDetails getRoomDetails(int roomNumber);
}
```